# Accessing JSON objects in a multi-returned data structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How would code the success callback function below to be able to access the objects in the returned JSON below. Obviously I won't be able to access the returned objects using, `success: function(data) {if (data.returned === true) {` anymore. How would I accomplish this?

jQuery Code:

```
$("#projects").click(function() {
                jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", dataType: "JSON",
                    url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/home/projectsSlider",
                    json: {returned: true}, success: function(data) {
                        if (data.returned === true) {
                            $("#resultProjects").html(JSON.stringify(data.Projects));
                            $("#resultScreenshots").html(JSON.stringify(data.Screenshots));

                            $("#content").fadeOut(150, function() {
                                $(this).replaceWith(projectsSlider(data.projectId, data.projectName, data.startDate, data.finishedDate, data.projectDesc, data.createdFor, data.contributors, data.screenshotURI, data.websiteURL), function() {
                                    $(this).fadeIn(150);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Returned JSON:

```
{
    "Projects": [
        {
            "projectId": "932713684f9073189ec7b",
            "projectName": "Cloud859Collective",
            "startDate": "April 19th, 2012",
            "finishedDate": "April 25th, 2012",
            "createdFor": "ClasskCreations",
            "contributors": "Mike Grigsby",
            "projectDesc": "This website was created with a friend in mind. His name is Kevin Johnson and he is a rapper. He needed a website that would allow him to host and share his music."
        },
        {
            "projectId": "10599012654f907093714e9",
            "projectName": "Nurbell Studio",
            "startDate": "April 15th, 2012",
            "finishedDate": "April 19th, 2012",
            "createdFor": "Nurbell LLC",
            "contributors": "Mike Grigsby",
            "projectDesc": "This is the page you are currently looking at. This is the official Nurbell homepage. Complete with a frontend and a backend."
        }
    ],
    "Screenshots": [
        {
            "screenshotURI": "http://nurbell.com/vd/1.0/images/project-data/kevo.png"
        },
        {
            "screenshotURI": "http://nurbell.com/vd/1.0/images/project-data/nurbell.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your asking here. I think you should take a look at javascript namespacing. That way you can create a property in your object (or namespace) and put the json result in that property.

something like this:

```
 var myProjects = {
     projects: null,

     getProjects: function() {
           // do the ajax thing with something like
           myProjects.projects = data.projects;
     },

     placeProjects: function() {
           if (myProjects.projects == null) myProjects.getProjects();
           $.each(myProjects.projects, function(i,e){
                //place project content
           }
     },
 }

 // define the click event
 $("#projects").click(myProjects.placeProjects());
```

The data will be stored until you delete it or reload the page. You can see this object in the DOM inspector in your firebug. Hope that helps

**EDIT :**

I've implemented the idea in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BTbJu/5
Run it, click on the text int the Div to load the first project. Keep clicking to rotate.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/j6XncXmd - something like this? I'm getting an error of: `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token }`. And also how should I access `data.projectId` in `projectsSlider()` ?

Comment: well, the each function iterates over all the elements in the array in the first argument (which is myProjects.projects) and then passes that element in the unnamed function with two parameters: i=index of element in the array (in case you want to change something like: myProjects.projects[i]) and the second one e=element is the content of the element. So you can refer to the projectId by e.projectId.... (you can also rename e to data in the function argument, but that would make things confusing I guess http://pastebin.com/PiDBBB0S

Comment: found another typo, also changed indentation for readability: http://pastebin.com/AcDBKtCR

Comment: and here's a jsFiddle which I debugged a bit. I had to strip the projectslider since I don't have that function. but you can see the logging of the values in the console. http://jsfiddle.net/BTbJu/1/

Comment: Okay I've worked out the code a little bit to fit my needs. http://pastebin.com/ghLkrJVE - A couple of things are going on here. 1, I'm getting a new error now: *Uncaught SyntaxError:  Unexpected identifier*. Also how do I get myprojects.projects to equal the json returned object and not a manual edition? Lastly, here is the projectsSlider() function: http://pastebin.com/3nzNGyuP. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: I've worked out a working example in http://jsfiddle.net/BTbJu/5/ I hope this resembles the behavior as you want it. There are various small bugs in your code (also in the projectsSlider) I changed it a bit also to make it work in JsFiddle (removed the iframe). Also, the returned json is a bit weird if the screenshots belong to the projects, they should be inside each project. I've commented the getJson out, just remove the hardcoded data and uncomment. If you can guarentee the projects and screenshots are in the same order, you can easily workout how to add them in the same way. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem correctly, but it seems you are concerned that your original json might get modified permanently when you call JSON.stringify.

No, JSON.Stringify will return a new string. Your original json, referenced by the closure argument 'data', will remain intact. You will be very well access all properties through the data reference.

In fact, it is data.projectId will be wrong within the closure scope, and should evaluate to undefined.

Try this:

```
$("#projects").click(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/home/projectsSlider",
        success: function (data) {
            var projects = data.Projects; //array
            var screenshots = data.Screenshots; //array

            //direct, one-off indexed
            console.log(projects[0].projectId);
            console.log(data.Projects[0].projectId);

            //looped with map
            projects.map(function(project, index) {
                console.log(project.projectId);
            });

            //traditional for
            for(var i1 = 0; i1 < projects.length; i1++) {
                console.log(projects[i1]);
            }

            //direct, one-off indexed
            console.log(screenshots[0].screenshotURI);
            console.log(data.Screenshots[0].screenshotURI);

            //looped
            screenshots.map(function(screenshot, index) {
                console.log(screenshot.screenshotURI);
            });

            if (data.returned === true) {
                //your stringify code etc.
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So how would I access the new structure? I'm completely stumped on this part.

Comment: would it be something like data.Projects.projectId... or something similar?

Comment: No, directly, you would do data.Projects[0].projectId. Better still, you'd run a loop over the Projects array.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LR8U8ADF - so something like this? As of right now it is not working on my page.